# MongoDB installation error "Verify that you have access to that directory"

Tags: mongodb, installation, windows-10

[image]

Hi,
As you can see from the image, I'm getting this error while installing MongoDB on Windows-10. I tried to uncheck installing Compass but I get the same error. I did try also the previous release of Mongo and I get the same error.
Please, any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: Try to install with Administrator privileges

Comment: I did, I get the same error :(

Comment: Follow these instructions [https://windowsreport.com/verify-you-have-access-to-directory/](https://windowsreport.com/verify-you-have-access-to-directory/)

Comment: I have finally resolved this issue by disabling the antivirus. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs and drivers in Windows should only be stored with administrator rights. In the case of installing EXE files as an administrator, in the context menu, which causes the file to be compressed with the right mouse button. There is no such option for the MSI package, but you can add it through the registry editor.
**How to Install an MSI Package with Administrator Rights** [Instructions](https://www.iguides.ru/main/apps/kak_ustanovit_paket_msi_s_pravami_administratora/#:%7E:text=%D0%92%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5,%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%20OK.)